# Eclipse: Treat a "dxml" file as a "xml" file?

Tags: xml, eclipse

So, I already downloaded some plugin to syntax-highlight XML files.  I work with these "DXML" files that are basically like XML files.  Is there a way to get Eclipse to think a .dxml file is a .xml file?

Answer (score 7):

Window->Preferences -> General -> Content Types. Select XML in the top half, then in the bottom half add `*.dxml`